# Same origin policy and CORS

Tags: javascript, http, security, cors

Let's I want to access data from my local site to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). It faces CORS restriction. Like the following picture
[image]

Does it mean that browser deny the user sending the request to Google's server or Google's server deny to response any feedback to the user? CORS restriction restricts JavaScript to fetching the data, so I am a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

CORS doesn't restrict, it does the opposite... it opens up.

Google is preventing your website from directly hitting their site from your site (or any site). Only the owner of the domain (google) you are trying to access can permit this.

Comment: I mean does browser deny sending the request to Google? Or actually sending but server denies to response?

Comment: The browser denies the response.